# How to increment a variable and print them in C?

Tags: c

I have the code:

```
printf("%d%c %s\n", 1, '.', buf.mtext);
```

which shows (if I have several messages):

```
1. (message1) 
1. (message2)
1. (message3)
```

But I want it to show:

```
1. (message1)
2. (message2)
3. (message3)
```

I just don't know how to get the number to increment.
Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: Update your question and include a complete, compilable example of the problem you are facing.  Also include the input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a number `x`:

```
int x;
```

We can initialize that number to `1`:

```
x = 1;
```

We can also increment that number by `1`:

```
x = x + 1;
```

We can even print the variable:

```
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an integer variable to hold the number you wish to print, and add 1 to it between calls to `printf`.